# Call api every x seconds not work with Ngrx + Angular

Tags: angular, timer, rxjs, ngrx, polling

I want to update a list with every 10 seconds for example. I used operator 'timer' but the api not show in second times on Chrome -> Network tab.

My process: dispatch Load action - my api - method GET - only be called one time in Network tab.
But if I created a button with function dispatch that action, my api will be called many times in Network tab/Chrome each time I click

My env: ngrx 7.4, rxjs 6.5.2, angular 7
So I don't know server auto block repeat calling api or if angular and ngrx is using cache

// My effect

````
  load$: Observable<Action> = this.action$.pipe(
    ofType<Load>(NotificationActionTypes.load),
    switchMap(() => timer(0, 10000)),
    switchMap((action) => {
      return this.notiService.getNotifications().pipe(map((res: any) => {
        return new LoadSuccess({
          result: res,
        });
      }));
    })
  );```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
See my image, 20/125 request, 125 continue increasing, 20/130, 20/145, but number 20 didn't increase


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKgbE.png
````

Comment: Do you want to dispatch `NotificationActionTypes.load`, or should it just call the api every 10 seconds?

Comment: @timdeschryver because I save notifications list in ngrx store and display list from it, after dispatch load action, I will dispatch LoadSuccess to save data. 
I mean I want to call api every 10 seconds to get the latest list. https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2018/03/05/advanced-caching-with-rxjs.html seems do like that, but it hasn't ngrx so I applied it but didn't work

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to dispatch an action if you want to reload every x seconds, you can just use the `timer` stream:

```
@Effect()
ping = interval(10000).pipe(
  switchMap((action) => {
    return this.notiService.getNotifications().pipe(map((res: any) => {
      return new LoadSuccess({
        result: res,
      });
    }));
}));
```

More info at [Start using ngrx/effects for this](https://timdeschryver.dev/posts/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this#using-rxjs-observables)

Comment: Hi @timdeschryver, I hadn't even know it before. But after apply this above code, the request still fire first time. Seems Chrome is blocking timer, it shows a warning ' [Violation] 'setInterval' handler took 70ms'.
If use old method, when page loaded done, no action dispatch. I click a button to dispatch load actions, it calls api every 10s correctly strangely. I don't know reason why

Comment: wait... "the request still fire first time" you don't want it to the fire the first time?

Comment: i want api called every 10s. But only fire 1st time, not second. When see logger, action still dispatch every 10s but api not call from second times ;)

Comment: I fixed it by adding a random params when call api GET